# Why am I getting a seg fault every time I try to store elements into an array in C?

Tags: c, pointers, io, segmentation-fault, malloc

So, I am trying to read a matrix from a file and store it into an array.

The matrix files are as follows:

```
2 3
1 5 8
6 3 9
```

With the first two digits on the first line representing Rows x Columns.

I seem to be getting an issue whenever I try to store something into my array, as I am able to simply reprint everything to the screen, but I am seg faulting whenever I try to add to an array.

My code is as follows:

```
double *read_matrix(char *filename){
     FILE *file=fopen(filename, "r");
 
     if(!file){
         fprintf(stderr, "An error has occurred. Wrong file name?\n");
         exit(errno);
     }

     double *data=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*4096);
     char *buff=malloc(sizeof(char *)*256);
     char *curr;

     while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),file)){
         curr=strtok_r(buff," ",&buff);
         int i=0;
         while(curr!=NULL){
             curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&buff);
             data[i]=strtod(curr,NULL); //this
             i++;
         }
     }
     return data;
}
```

Whenever I debug with GDB and use the backtrace command, it brings me to the line with comment `//this`.

I am having troubles understanding what I have done wrong, and I'm starting to go mad!

Comment: use perror to print the error *message* human-readably

Comment: This is wrong: `char *buff=malloc(sizeof(char *)*256);`

Comment: It looks like this line `curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&buff);` should be after the `strtod` line unless you want to discard the first value.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Indeed. Rookies am I right? Seems I've also got some other error too, my data isn't properly stored in the data array after strtod. Thanks!

Comment: Avoid  mis-allocation.  `char *buff=malloc(sizeof(char *)*256);` ---> `char *buff=malloc(sizeof *buf * 256);`

Comment: This is wrong: `while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),file))`. `buff` is only a pointer, not the whole buffer. You will only read 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: This is also wrong: `curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&buff);` After this call, `buff` will be modified. You cannot use it again to read data into the memory you received from `malloc`

Comment: And one more: `int i=0;` You do this inside the loop `while(fgets...)...`. This means you will reuse the first few elements of `data` for every line you read from the file. In the end you will only keep the values from last line. BTW: How would the calling function know, how many elements are stored in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
     while(curr!=NULL){
         curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&buff);
         data[i]=strtod(curr,NULL); //this
         i++;
     }
```

should be

```
     while(curr!=NULL){
         data[i]=strtod(curr,NULL); //this
         i++;
         curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&buff);  // Looking for next token shall 
                                         // be the last statement
     }
```

Further this line

```
char *buff=malloc(sizeof(char *)*256);
```

is wrong. It should be

```
char *buff=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
                         ^^^^
                         No *
```

But in general for your `malloc` it's much better to use the form:

```
 double *data = malloc(4096 * sizeof *data);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^

 char *buff=malloc(256 * sizeof *buff);
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

By using `sizeof *varname` you avoid simple type mismatches as the one you had.

Comment: What does sizeof *buff actually do, if me calling malloc is me allocating memory for buff? Is this the size of a char pointer multiplied by constant 256?

Comment: Since `buff` is a char-pointer, `*buff` is a char so `sizeof *buff` is the same as `sizeof(char)`. It's just a safer way of writing your malloc

Answer (score 1):

You don't check the value of `curr` before calling `strtod()`.

This:

```
(...)
         while(curr!=NULL){
             curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&buff);
             data[i]=strtod(curr,NULL); //this
             i++;
         }
```

Should be:

```
(...)
         while(1){
             curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&buff);
             if (curr == NULL)
                 break; 
             data[i]=strtod(curr,NULL); //this
             i++;
         }
```

Comment: I believe this solution is incorrect, as it will still discard the result of the first call to `strtok_r` (which happens outside the loop). Therefore, the call to `strtod` must appear before the call to `strtok_r` in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value from `strtok_r` just before the line in question.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't even need to use strtok. Just use strtod, which manage white spaces :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double *read_matrix(char *filename){
   FILE *file=fopen(filename, "r");

   if(!file){
      fprintf(stderr, "An error has occurred. Wrong file name?\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   double *data = malloc(10 * sizeof(double));
   char *buff = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

   char *end_pointer;
   char *newline_pos;

   int i = 0;

   while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),file)){
      //removing newline character read by fgets
      if ((newline_pos = strchr(buff, '\n')) != NULL) {
         *newline_pos = '\0';
      }

      while (strlen(buff) != 0) {
         data[i] = strtod(buff,&end_pointer);
         buff = end_pointer;
         i++;
      }
   }
   //convenient for printf output
   data[i] = '\0';
   return data;
}

int main(void) {
   char file[] = "matrix.txt";
   double *array = read_matrix(file);

   int i = 0;
   while (array[i] != '\0') {
      printf("%f ",array[i]);
      i++;
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code that haven't been addressed in the other answers:

```
double *read_matrix(char *filename){
     FILE *file=fopen(filename, "r");
 
     if(!file){
         fprintf(stderr, "An error has occurred. Wrong file name?\n");
         exit(errno);
     }

     double *data=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*4096);
     char *buff=malloc(sizeof(char *)*256);
```

You want a buffer for characters, not for pointers.

```
     char *curr;

     while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),file)){
```

`sizeof` does not evaluate to the size of your buffer but only to the size of a `char*` which is 4 or 8 on most systems. This might not be enough for a complete line.

```
         curr=strtok_r(buff," ",&buff);
```

You are modifying `buff` inside the loop. When you use it for `fgets` in next iteration of the loop, you will not use the address you got from `malloc`.

```
         int i=0;
```

You set the index for your array to 0 for each line you read. In the end this will only keep the values from the last line.

```
         while(curr!=NULL){
             curr=strtok_r(NULL," ",&buff);
             data[i]=strtod(curr,NULL); //this
             i++;
         }
     }
     return data;
```

This only hold the numbers from last line or even only the numbers in first 8 bytes of last line.
How does the caller know how many numbers you have read at all?

```
}
```

A fixed solution could look like this:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 256
double *read_matrix(char *filename, int *numread) {
    FILE *file=fopen(filename, "r");
 
    if(!file){
        fprintf(stderr, "An error has occurred. Wrong file name?\n");
        exit(errno);
    }

    double *data = malloc(sizeof(double)*4096);
    char *buff = malloc(BUFFSIZE);
    char *curr = NULL;
    char *savetr = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(buff, BUFFSIZE, file)){
        curr = strtok_r(buff, " ", &saveptr);
        while(curr != NULL){
            data[i] = strtod(curr, NULL);
            i++;
            curr=strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr);
        }
    }
    if (numread != NULL)
        *numread=i;
    return data;
}
```